# IBM RAD keystore location

Tags: keystore, ibm-rad

im using RAD and its default jdk (\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre\lib\security) and need to find the keystore location as it appears to be corrupted (or the JDK is using the wrong keystore) and need to either regenerate or point to a different location. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file is located under \IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\lib\security.